# Determine the error-probability of biased coin tosses using chernoff-bounds

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, binomial-distribution

Let's assume we have a **biased coin** with probabilities $\frac{4}{5}$ and $\frac{1}{5}$ and we don't know to which event (head or tail) the probabilities belong to.

But we want to **decide it by majority** after **n** tosses.

(1) What's the **probability of error** of such a decision?

My approach:

Let $X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ be the sum of the outcomes of this **binomial distributed** random variable after $n$ tosses.
As a given note says, we can use the following Chernoff-bound.

$$
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(X \leq (1-\beta) \cdot E(X)) \leq \exp(- \frac{E[X] \beta²}{2}), \beta\in (0,1)
\end{equation*}
$$

If we represent the event head by $1$ and tail by $0$ and the sum $X$ is greater then $n/2$, head should be the one event with probability $4/5$ right?

Using the Chernoff-bound gives us

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X \leq \frac{n}{2}) &= \mathbb{P}(X \leq (1-\frac{3}{8})\frac{4n}{5})\\
&\leq \exp(- \frac{9n}{160})
\end{align*}
$$

So, how to move on and what is the **probability of error** now?

Thanks and happy Easter!

Comment: Is there an extra minus sign in your statement of the bound?

Comment: Aren't you finished?  It seems to me that you've shown that the probability of error is at most $e^{-9n/160}.$  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @saulspatz At first, many thx for your reply! Yes, this minus sign is extra. But e.g. it does not matter if there is $X \geq (1+\beta)E$  or $X \leq (1-\beta)E$. It changes only the factor at the exp function to $\frac{1}{3}$ if you use first one. **I don't understand, why this exactly is the probability of error?** If i say " yes 4/5 belongs to Head because $X \geq \frac{n}{2}$.  The prob. of error for me is: How high is the probability that i'am wrong?!

Comment: oh thx. It was one minus to much!